# API callback from Paypal when there is dispute or refund

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to setup a website with a backend to capture papal orders and payments using their orders API.

Everything is expected to be controlled using code so is there any way paypal will send a callback when there is a dispute or customer asks for a refund ? i.e. if there are many orders it would be hard to keep track of disputes by reading emails.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check out the PayPal API documentation. **The [Disputes API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/customer-disputes/v1/) is what you are looking for.**

Comment: Thanks I did check that API, it is only about listing and addressing the disputes. I wondered if we can setup a webhook or a callback when a dispute happens.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a webhook listener on [the REST app](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) for the events you want to listen to (specify `*` for all). There are events for disputes and refunds; see the list in the [PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/#disputes)